# $\varphi(u)$ is invertible in $R'$ iff no invertible element of $R$ belongs to $\ker \varphi$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ring-homomorphism

> Assume the surjective ring homomorphism $\varphi: R \longrightarrow
>  R'$, where $R$ is a ring with unity. Also let $u$ be an invertible
>   element of $R$. Show that $\varphi(u)$ is invertible in $R'$ iff no
>   invertible element of $R$ belongs to $\ker \varphi$.

$\Rightarrow:$ Suppose $\varphi(u)$ is invertible in $R'$. Since $0$ cannot be invertible (unless $R = \{0\}$, but then we wouldn't have $1$), we have that 
$$
\varphi(u) \neq 0 \Rightarrow u \notin \ker \varphi
$$

$\Leftarrow:$ Since $\varphi$ is surjective, for every $r' \in R'$, there exists $r \in R$ such that $\varphi(r) = r'$ and thus
$$
r'\varphi(1) = \varphi(r)\varphi(1) = \varphi(r\cdot 1) = \varphi(r) = r' \Rightarrow \varphi(1) \,\text{unity of}\, R'
$$

Also, since $u$ is invertible in $R$, there exists an $r \in R$ such that $ur = 1$ and since $\varphi(u) \neq 0$

$$
\varphi(u)\varphi(r) = \varphi(ur) = \varphi(1)
$$
Therefore $\varphi(r)$ is the inverse of $\varphi(u)$ and thus $\varphi(u)$ is invertible.

Comment: In your $\implies$, you need to show that *no* invertible element of $R$ belongs to $\ker \varphi$. You've just shown that $u\notin\ker\varphi$. (You've actually made a typo and written "$\varphi(u)\notin\ker\varphi$".)

Comment: $R= \{0\}$ has $0=1$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a unitary ring (i.e. with 1), denote by $R^*$ the set of its invertible elements, if the ring has no unity then set $R^*=\emptyset$.

In your statement you need to assume that both $R$ and $R'$ are rings with $1$ and that $\varphi(1_R)=1_{R'}$ (i.e. $\varphi$ is an homomorphism of unitary rings), otherwise $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 2\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $\varphi(x)=2x$ gives you a counterexample as $\varphi$ satisfies the conditions but $\varphi(1)=2$.

Now about $\Rightarrow$

- note that $\ker(\varphi)$ is an ideal, hence if it contains an invertible element then it is $\ker(\varphi)=R$ and $\varphi=0$. So if you assume $\varphi \neq 0$ then it has to be $\ker(\varphi) \cap R^*=\emptyset$.
- if you still don't know what ideals are, then to conclude the same proceed like this:
  if there were $v \in R^*$ s.t. $\varphi (v) = 0 $ then given any $x \in R$ you would have $\varphi(x)=\varphi(x v v^{-1})= 0$, thus one would have $\varphi=0$.

The only way you could have the condition $\ker(\varphi) \cap R^*=\emptyset$ to fail is that $\varphi=0$. Whether this is possible for a unitary ring homomorphism much depends on what you admit to be a unitary ring.
You may want to regard $\{0\}$ as a unitary ring in which $1=0$: it depends on whether you put the axiom $1 \neq 0$ in the theory of unitary rings. If you admit $\{0\}$ as "degenerate" ring with unity, then $0: R \rightarrow \{0\}$ is a unitary ring homomorphism, otherwise all homomorphism of unitary rings $\varphi: R \rightarrow R'$ are $\varphi \neq 0$.

About $\Leftarrow$

- note that $\varphi(u)\varphi(u^{-1})=\varphi (1_R)=\varphi(1_{R'})$ (which is essentially your argument), but note that if you admit a $\{0\}$ unitary ring and $0$ unitary rings homomorphisms into it, then $\varphi(u)\varphi(u^{-1})=\varphi (1_R)=\varphi(1_{R'})$ still holds in any case, it just happens that $1_{R'}=0_{R'}$.

Comment: So, is my $\Leftarrow$ argument valid? I don't get why do we need the fact that no invertible element belongs to the kernel, if it works for the $\{0\}$ case too?

Comment: It is a matter of definition of what is an invertible element in the degenerate case. If $R'=\{0\}$ you could say that every element of $R'$ is invertbile as $R'$ has only one element $1_{R'}=0_{R'}$.